# Which package should I install for flask.ext.login and flask.login?

Tags: python, flask

I am spiking Flask based login and signup webapp.
I downloaded [flask-login-example](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example).

When I run the two example files([flask-login-example.py](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/blob/master/flask-login-example.py), [flasklogin.py](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/blob/master/flasklogin.py)), I got error messages.

For importing `flask.ext.login`:

```sh
https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/blob/master/flasklogin.py
```

For importing `flask.login`:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.login'
```

I installed `flask-login` package using the `pip3` command, I got the same error messages for each example. What's wrong with my code? Which Python package should I install?

Comment: how is it being imported?

Comment: `from flask.login import LoginManager`

Comment: and another is `from flask.ext.login import LoginManager`

Comment: It worked when I modify the import statement as `from flask_login import loginManager`, but why this incompatibility happened?

Comment: well, I almost sure that you have installed this package(flask-login on pypi): https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login

Comment: So, it should not be installed via `pip`?

Comment: https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/issues/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you've provided as example is a outdated reference source.
Looking on issues ([this](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example/issues/6)) in the same [repository](https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example) it's possible notice that package imports do not reflect the [current](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login) package version anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In new version of flask, use 
    from flask_login import LoginManager
and you'll found lots of package and imported this way in new version.

Comment: Thank you. Expecting your more help on my future login-related questions.